# Which one is better approach so as to able to use wrapper class read() / write() method with android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource() method?

Tags: java, android

```
//Reading a image file from @drawable res folder and writing to a file on external sd card
//below one works no doubt but I want to imrpove it:
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);   //File file.........                
InputStream is =getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.an_image);
byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(b);
os.write(b);
is.close();
os.close();
```

In above code I am using basic io classes to read and write. **My question** is what can I do in order to able to use wrapper classes like say DataInputStream/ BufferedReaderd or PrintStream / BufferedWriter /PrintWriter.

As openRawResources(int id ) returns InputStream ;

to read a file from res I either need to typecast like this:

```
DataInputStream is = (DataInputStream) getResources().openRawResource(R.drawble.an_image));
```

or I can link the stream directly like this:

```
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.greenball));
```

and then I may do this to write it to a file on sd card:

```
PrintStream ps =new PrintStream (new FileOutputStream(file));

while(s=is.readLine()!=null){
ps.print(s);
}
```

So is that correct approach ? which one is better? Is there a better way?better practice..convention?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

If `openRawResource()` is documented to return an `InputStream` then you cannot rely on that result to be any more specific kind of `InputStream`, and in particular, you cannot rely on it to be a `DataInputStream`.  Casting does not change that; it just gives you the chance to experience interesting and exciting exceptions.  If you want a `DataInputStream` wrapping the the result of `openRawResource()` then you **must** obtain it via the `DataInputStream` constructor.  Similarly for any other wrapper stream.

HOWEVER, do note that `DataInputStream` likely is not the class you want.  It is appropriate for reading back data that were originally written via a `DataOutputStream`, but it is *inappropriate* (or at least offers no advantages over any other `InputStream`) for reading general data.

Furthermore, your use of `InputStream.available()` is incorrect.  That method returns the number of bytes that can *currently* be read from the stream *without blocking*, which has only a weak relationship with the total number of bytes that could be read from the stream before it is exhausted (if indeed it ever is).

Moreover, your code is also on shaky ground where it assumes that `InputStream.read(byte[])` will read enough bytes to fill the array.  It probably will, since that many bytes were reported available, but that's not guaranteed.  To copy from one stream to another, you should instead use code along these lines:

```
private final static int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

void copyStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int nread;

    while ( (nread = in.read(buffer) != 0 ) do {
        out.write(buffer, 0, nread);
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to use wrapper classes, we need to read data byte by byte? right?

Comment: You can wrap the InputStream and/or OutputStream if you wish, and use the wrapped streams (in the same way as above), but it confers no particular advantage.  Do note that you should generally do this buffer by buffer, though, as shown, not byte by byte.